# Prove f(x) is a valid pdf, and if x is a random variable with pdf f(x), find E(X).

Tags: probability-distributions

Lads, I need some insight here.

Given our $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac2\pi}e^{-(x^2/2)}$ where x is non-negative, I have to prove that $f(x)$ is a valid pdf.

My work done so far:
I've tried to pull out the constant, $\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$, out of the integral, to make the integral look like the normal distribution and I keep getting 2 instead of 1, which is not what I want because I have to get a 1 to prove that it's a valid pdf. What am I missing here?

Apologies for my poor symbols.

Comment: Are you forgetting to use that $x$ is non-negative? This would account for the factor of 2, since $$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\,\text{d}x = \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\,\text{d}x$$

Comment: I don't know if that changes anything when you are proving if it's a valid pdf

Comment: The reason I said this is I wanted to know what integral you were computing to get 2. If $x$ is non-negative, then you are integrating over $(0,\infty)$, but most standard computations of the Gaussian integral are over $(-\infty,\infty)$. Can you show the process you used to get $2$ so I can more pointedly address your concern?